# How can I protect my home against the creatures of the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I currently live in a Nether Ruin. My not-so-sweet home always seems to be overrun by Zombie Pigmen, Wither Skeletons, and Blazes. What am I supposed to do to keep them away?